# Batch render lots of layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photos

I have many layers for playing cards. They are all hidden right now. They are all named, e.g.: 2h, 3h, 2s, 3s...

Right now I'm manually enabling it, saving it as `2s.png`, disabling it and so on. Is there a better way to do this, can Photoshop save each layer as a png using the layer name?